# Is there a better way to do if A==B && B==C && C==D?

Tags: c

Is there a shorthand for "if A, B, and C are all equal to D"? In the scenario I'm in right now, I'm actually only interested in seeing if they are all equal, not their actual value, so something for "if A, B, C, and D are the same" works too.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you could find a faster implementation, *that makes a measurable difference to your application*.  Having said that, what types are A, B, C and D?

Comment: Question doesn't seem to ask for anything faster, but rather just if there is a shorthand (for easier typing/reading), which seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: Either/or, really. If it's faster *and* more readable, great! I'm looking for any and all alternatives that I might find useful. The variables are all integers in this case.

Comment: @Tim: The stated form is the most *expressive* one I can imagine, short of perhaps a macro `ARE_ALL_EQUAL(A, B, C, D)`

Comment: Beyond quibbling that `A == D && B == D && C == D` would represent 'if A, B and C are all equal to D' slightly better, there isn't going to be anything better for comparing 4 values for equality.  If you need to generalize to N values, you may end up with a loop over elements of an array, or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged as C, but If C++11 is allowed you could define `all_equal` as follows:

```
template <typename T1>
inline bool all_equal(T1&& val) {
 return true;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
inline bool all_equal(T1&& val1, T2&& val2, Ts&&... rest) {
  return val1 == val2 && all_equal(std::forward<T2>(val2), std::forward<Ts>(rest)...);
}
```

Example usage:

```
all_equal(3);    // true
all_equal(3, 3); // true
all_equal(3, 4); // false
all_equal(x, y, z); // would be expanded to 'x == y && y == z'
```

There is no limit to the number of arguments.

If you want to stick with C, you could use [variable-length argument lists](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html), but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Isn't it too costly to use recursion for this simple task? Aside from this, it's a pretty solution.

Comment: @DavidFrank Since there probably won't be *any* function calls at all here in practice, no, it won't be too costly a solution. But assuming the question is correctly tagged *C*, it isn't a viable solution, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau What do you mean? For example, `all_equal(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` needs 3+1 function calls, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DavidFrank Yes, but an optimizing compiler should be able to inline it.

Comment: Well, in this case +1 for the nice solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You're unlikely to ever encounter a scenario where this is likely to be a speed limit. 
Often however, minimizing the branches in the loop is fastest.

Id do

```
!(a^b | b^c | c^d)
```

I suspect the bit operator `|` will be faster than the short circuit `||` in wildplasser answer, at least when the result is not the same every time the loop is executed
Don't assume though. If it actually matters try both and measure it.

It's pretty short syntax though

Comment: Such micro-optimizations are very rarely useful. You have to remember that today's compilers write _much better_ code than an assembler programmer does, given some prodding in the "optimize this code" department. If you require speed, think of better algorithms long before statement-level twiddling.

Comment: I admit its unlikely to be in any way significant (you never know), but I like the syntax, and I don't think compilers will switch between logical and bit operations, and I've spent a fair amount of my life looking at profiled generated assembly.

Comment: @vonbrand: Compilers generally do not generate better code than skilled assembly programmers. They generate more code more quickly and are better than non-assembly programmers trying to write assembly but definitely have limits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, an experienced assembly language programmer putting all their effort into it might get better code, doing routine work they won't. I remember that one of the objectives of the BLISS compiler <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLISS> in the '70s was to generate better code than experienced assembly programmers in their everyday work, and they succeded. In those days assembly language programming was still common for "system level programming", machines were _much_ simpler (no out-of-order execution, no pipelines, no multiple units in the CPU, ...). So I stand by my assertion.

Comment: @vonbrand: No, beating the compiler is routine for good programmers. We do it regularly. It requires more knowledge and time than most people are willing to put into the work, but it is not extraordinary, largely because humans understand code and its context better than compilers, and there are many optimizations that remain beyond what compilers can do. This is not a theoretical assertion; it is direct experience on a routine basis.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, do it for a whole _program_ (or at least a substantial function) instead of just a performance-critical snippet. The later I've done sometimes and beat the compiler (if not, I'd just remove my hack), the former I know very well that I'd be _very thoroughly_ beaten.

Comment: @vorbrand: There is no benefit in writing an entire program in assembly. Once you have optimized the performance-critical sections, the benefit (slight speed improvements) of writing the rest in assembly is not worth the cost (human labor). I asserted that skilled humans write better assembly than compilers, not that they are cheaper or more efficient.

Comment: I have to say that a compiler can NOT in a general case (depending on data types) legally optimize a==b && b==c to !(a^b | b^c) The && is a short circuit operator, and the compiler is not allowed to execute the b==c until it has checked a==b, so therefore uses jumps. It is quite legal for a programmer to use the a==b and the short circuit operator to prevent c being dereferenced in the case that it is a null pointer for example, although I would consider that confusing style for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Short-circuited XOR-trick:

```
int abcd(unsigned aa, unsigned bb, unsigned cc, unsigned dd)
{
#define FOUR_UNEQUAL(a,b,c,d)  ((a^b^c^d) || (a^b) || (c^d) || (b^c)) ? 1 : 0

return FOUR_UNEQUAL(aa,bb,cc,dd);
}
```

Generated assembly (GCC 4.6.1-9ubuntu3):

```
type   abcd, @function
abcd:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    %esi, %eax
        xorl    %edi, %eax
        xorl    %edx, %eax
        cmpl    %ecx, %eax
        jne     .L7
        cmpl    %esi, %edi
        jne     .L7
        cmpl    %ecx, %edx
        setne   %al
        cmpl    %edx, %esi
        setne   %dl
        orl     %edx, %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L7:
        movl    $1, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

And, as mentioned earlier, the speed gains are marginal (if any).

Comment: The speed gains will be lost by the jumps.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a macro to do it:

```
#DEFINE ARE_ALL_EQUALS(A, B, C, D) (((A) == (B)) && ((B) == (C)) && ((C) == (D)))
```

But beware of multiple evaluation of B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a Macro like

```
#define ALL_EQUAL(A, B, C, D) ((A) == (B)) && ((B) == (C)) && ((C) == (D))
```

but I can't see any advantage over the usual thing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "fastest" way would be to compare pairs, and then check the result of pairs:
`(A == B) && (C == D) && (A == C)` as indeed indicated by OP. For more elements, work pairs, and combine results in a complete binary tree. Might go as far as reordering so the `&&` fail as early as possible on average. In any case, this is a *very* specialized operation (can't remember offhand if I've ever done something like that), so providing extra notation for this would probably hurt more than what could be gained.

As always: Write the code that is most readable first, and massage for performance if and where measurements show it is worthwhile. The human time (writing, debugging, maintaining code) is much more valuable than the computer's time running it, except in *extremely* rare occasions.